# Class inheritance, forcing new classes to implement certain functions

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, interface

Ok so i'm messing around with a few things, specifically interfaces.

Say I have a class 'Cat' with its base as 'Animal' Animal has a method in it like so

```
public virtual void Walk()
{
    // Do walking stuff
}
```

So Cat would override it with:

```
public override void Walk()
{
    // Do cat specific walking stuff
}
```

Simple right?

Here's my question though, is there a way to force cat to override the base Walk() method? So if another developer added a Dog class they would be forced to implement their own Walk method (even if it was just base.Walk()) ?

So interfaces kind of solves this, this is what i've tried

Cat : Animal : Interface
Animal has to implement the Walk method, but Cat doesn't

Cat : Animal, Interface
Cat has to implement the Walk method, but if the developer doesn't add or forgets the ',Interface' then it will 'break' it.

can someone give me some pointer as to go about this ?

Thanks.

**Edit 1**

Here's what I am aiming for, i hope it makes it clearer.

```
public class Animal
{
    public Animal()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Animal");
    }

    public virtual void Walk()
    {

    }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat() : base()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cat");
    }

    public override void Walk()
    { 

    }
}

class Dog : Animal
{

    public Dog()
    {

    }

    public override void Walk()
    {
        // Dog implementation 
        // and / or calls base method
        base.Walk();
    }
}
```

This would create an error

```
class Dog : Animal
{

    public Dog()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is when you want to mark the base class and the base method as `abstract`.

```
abstract class Animal 
{
    public abstract void Walk(); 
}
```

Derived classes will have to implement `Walk` in order to be instantiated.

```
class Cat : Animal 
{
    public override void Walk() { }
}
```

Note: this change makes `Animal` not instantiable on its own, all references to it would be via more derived classes.

```
Animal animal = new Cat();
```

> Here's my question though, is there a way to force cat to override the
>   base Walk() method? **So if another developer added a Dog class they
>   would be forced to implement their own Walk method (even if it was
>   just base.Walk())** ?

This is where you have a disconnect, or opposing goals. To force children to implement a method, you mark it abstract. To allow the child to elect to use the base implementation, it would need to be virtual, which would then make it optional to override. Even if you were to basically use a template method pattern and make *parts* of the algorithm abstract to push the implementation into lower classes, the problem remains the same: you cannot force an override while also leaving a default implementation.*

You need to determine if you want to have a base implementation, in part or in whole.

---

*You chould theoretically have `abstract void Walk(); protected void WalkImpl() { }` in the base, which would allow the children to choose to invoke `WalkImpl` if they didn't want to provide their own implementation.

```
class Cat : Animal
{
     protected override void Walk() { base.WalkImpl(); }
}
```

I'm not sure how I feel about this, however. You're basically making the derived classes' authors' lives more difficult by forcing an override while still allowing them to use a default behavior. *If the default behavior can be used, simply go with `virtual` and trust authors of derived classes to override when **they** feel it is appropriate.*

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, The problem with this is that 'public abstract void Walk();' cannot have any implementation so you can't do base.Walk()

Comment: I just finished editing in a note about that. Check the revision.

Comment: I've added a edit to my post, please have a look if this is possible or not.

Comment: What you want: no. Check the latest revision for an approach which I frankly do not recommend, but I feel is the closest you are going to get.

Comment: Thanks Anthony ill have a think about what I truly want to do and if its feasible based  on what you've given me.