# Interface for derived class

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance, interface

Is it possible to force the derived classes of a class to implement an interface?

Let's say I have Interface `IImportantStuff` and Classes `Base` and `DerivedA`, `DerivedB`,`DerivedC` and ...

I want to force **DerivedA**, **DerivedB**, **DerivedC** and all other classes that will inherit Base class in future (classes I may design in future) to implement **IImportantStuff**.

Editted:

As another question, Each inherited class (derived from Base class) works with a certain Entity (say Customer, Shopkeeper, Personnel) and I want to force the derived classes to declare their Entity to prevent the programmers on my team creating a class inherited from Base without defining the Entity. I wanted to do this via Generics and Interfaces so that on the Base form they can access the properties and members of the Entity.

For example

```
class Base<T> { public T Entity {get; set;} }

class MidClass : Base {}

class Customer
{
    public string CustomerName {get; set;}
}

class Shopkeeper
{
    public int ShopkeeperID {get; set;}
}

class Shop1 : Base<ShopKeeper>
{
    //1. Force the programmer to implement ShopkeeperID
    //2. Be able to access the properties of Shopkeeper
    void MyMethod()
    {
        var skid = this.Entity.ID;
    }
}

class Shop2 : Base<Customer>
{
    void MyMethod()
    {
        var skid = this.Entity.CustomerName;
    }
}
```

I want **Shop1** and **Shop2** to inherit Base class, not directly the interface, because my co-programmers may forget to inherit from Interface on their classes. So I want to do the force on MidClass and their classes which are inherited from MidClass should implement the interface.

Comment: Probably same as:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652885/class-inheritance-forcing-new-classes-to-implement-certain-functions

Comment: Could you show the class definitions?

Answer (score 3):

one way is to declare Base class as abstract and make methods and properties IImportantStuff absract:

```
public interface IImportantStuff
{
    void Action();
}

public abstract class Base: IImportantStuff
{
    public abstract void Action();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As long as your `Base` class implements `IImportantStuff` all derived classes will implement it as well.

If you want derived methods to provide implementations you'd need to make `Base` class abstract and mark all methods/properties from that interface `abstract`.